# How to calculate number of hours when hours per day changed during the course of the project in Python 2.7 Django-admin

Tags: python-2.7, django-admin

For example, I have to input hours per day and yesterday it was 4.0 then I want to change it to 6.0 today. How can I calculate the total number of hours, retaining the previous hours and adding it to the new hours, in a given date range?

Comment: tried what before asking?

Comment: I have no idea how I should start or what algorithm I should do.

Comment: I want to access the history and get the previous hours but how can I do that? I am still new to django-admin and python.

Comment: You have to understand, SO is not a place for solving basic problems, which can be easily sought online. Stackoverflow help when the problem can not be easily solved even after searching and learning. Have you ever tried to learn something first or searching some tutorials for reference?

Comment: By the way, the question is even not clear enough. Please try to solve it before asking....